# Inverse of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, linear-transformations

What is the inverse of the following linear transformation?

> $T^{\theta}:R^2\rightarrow R^2$
>
> a reflection in the line through the origin which forms an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis.

I have little idea how to approach this question, please provide an explanation of how I could answer this.

Thanks

Comment: Write out the linear map first ?

Answer (score 1):

It is the reflexion itself.

What is the image of the image of a point by a reflexion?

Comment: What is the matrix of the transformation though?